# Change foreach to lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, foreach

I need a help with simpify this statement. How to change foreach to lambda

```
var r = mp.Call(c => c.GetDataset());   // returns IEnumerable of dataset      
foreach (DatasetUserAppsUsage item in r)
{
   datasetUserAppsUsage.Merge(item.AppsUsageSummary);
}
```

Comment: can you please wrap your code in a code block? The symbol looks like `{ }`

Answer (score 15):

lambdas and loops are orthogonal. It is inappropriate to try to change them to brute-force one into the other. That code is fine. Leave it.

You *can* get `.ForEach` implementations, but it isn't going to make the code better (in fact, it will be harder to follow, i.e. worse), and it won't be more efficient (in fact, it will be marginally slower, i.e. worse).

Comment: A foreach vs. `List<T>.ForEach` always reminds me of the following article - http://diditwith.net/2006/10/05/PerformanceOfForeachVsListForEach.aspx

Comment: @JaredPar Very interesting article. I was surprised.

Comment: @JaredPar yes, but calling .ToList() first just to use ForEach() will slam that somewhat :)

Comment: certainly yes that's an issue :).  Wasn't trying to imply this was a better solution for this particular scenario. Just that debates of this kind always remind me of that article because the conclusions it draws were very counterintuitive to me.  Makes a bit more sense though when you consider the implementation details a bit.

Answer (score 12):

You can do the following

```
r.ToList().ForEach(item => datasetUserAppsUsage.Merge(item.AppsUsageSummary);
```

Comment: Marc Gravell 1 - JaredPar 0.5 ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I don't think I would merge this into a single lambda.  You could do:

```
mp.Call(c => c.GetDataset()).ToList().ForEach(item =>  datasetUserAppsUsage.Merge(item.AppsUsageSummary));
```

However, I would avoid it, as it's [purposefully causing side effects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx), which really violates the expectations of LINQ, and is not very clear in its intent.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that lambdas purpose it different, but sometimes I use this trick:

```
mp.Call(c => c.GetDataset())
  .All(a => { datasetUserAppsUsage.Merge(a.AppsUsageSummary); return true; });
```

The trick is to use **All**() and return **true** to avoid break.
And do not change the underlying collection when inside enumerator of course :)